# Elasticsearch has_child not returning back all parent documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is the mapping data for both `customer` and `customer_query` documents, where `customer` is the parent and `customer_query` the child document.

[image: customer]
[image: customer_query]

When I run a generic search against all `customer_query` documents, I get back 127 documents.

[image: all customer_query docs]

However, when I run the following query against the parent

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/fts_index/customer/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "has_child" : {
        "type" : "customer_query",
        "query" : { "match_all": {} }
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

I get back only 23 documents. There should be 127 documents returned back since each `customer_query` document has a unique parent id assigned to it that does match up to the `customer` type.

When I retry creating my `customer_query` documents, I get a different number of documents back each time leading me to think it is some kind of shard issue. I have 5 shards assigned to the index.

```
{
  "took" : 59,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 23,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "fts_index",
      "_type" : "customer",
      "_id" : "7579f2c0-e4e4-4374-82d7-bf4c508fc51d",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_routing" : "8754248f-1c51-46bf-970a-493c349c70a7",
      "_parent" : "8754248f-1c51-46bf-970a-493c349c70a7",
      ....
```

I can't wrap my head around this issue. Any thoughts on what could be the issue? Is this a routing issue? If so, how do I rectify that with my search?

Comment: what happen when you run it multiple times, do you get `23` each time? how many nodes and replicas are you using?

Comment: You are sure each customer_query doc has a unique parent?

Comment: I figured out the issue... the _routing key being set to the same as _parent was making it so the child documents were not being on the same shard as the parent, hence could not be found. Properly setting the _routing key fixed my issue.